# Browser using JEditorPane forcing blue background

Tags: java, swing, url, colors, jeditorpane

This is the code I'm using to display google in a JEditorPane

```
String url="http://google.com";    
editorPane.setEditable(false);
    try {
        editorPane.setPage(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
```

But for some reason the background will always be a blue colour, doesn't matter if I call

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: For which component have you called `setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`? You are setting background color of its parent. Please share some code. `editorPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);` is work perfectly for me and I have added it into `JScrollPane`.

Comment: I have tried it on both the editorpane and the container which contains it. I don't know what code I should add, there is no more relevant code besides creating the container, giving it a border layout, creating the editorpane and adding it to the container. The background is simply blue

Comment: Try this one [JTextPane text background color does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285526/jtextpane-text-background-color-does-not-work).

Comment: *"This is the code I'm using to display google in a JEditorPane"*  The `JEditorPane` was never intended to render 'real world' HTML.  Note that it only supports a **subset** of ***HTML 3.2*** & (very) basic CSS.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the same problem, but instead, I got a blue foreground. I have a white background, which is correct. But I have blue text for any code formatted in a `<span>` or a `<font>`, while I have white text (regardless of background and foreground color from Java code) for text in bare `<p>`. Note that everything is in the same `<p>`, white text or blue text, span or font or bare.

Comment: However, background color works in my code. You can find the source code for my project from [GitHub](https://github.com/PEMapModder/PocketMine-GUI/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/pemapmodder/pocketminegui/gui/server/ConsolePanel.java) (I hadn't got time to simplify the problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @AndrewThompson noted in the comments `JEditorPane` is really behind, it supports only a subset of HTML 3.2 and CSS1, and isn't really cable of rendering any modern web pages.

I strongly suggest using an alternative, like:

- **[JavaFX WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html)**

  Code Snippet: (no dependencies, you can run it as-is)

  ```
  import javafx.application.Platform;
  import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
  import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;

  public class JavaFxBrowser implements Runnable {
      private WebEngine webEngine;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JavaFxBrowser());
      }

      public void loadURL(final String url) {
          Platform.runLater(() -> {
              webEngine.load(url);
          });
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          // setup UI
          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

          JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
          frame.getContentPane().add(jfxPanel);
          frame.pack();

          Platform.runLater(() -> {
              WebView view = new WebView();
              webEngine = view.getEngine();

              jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
          });

          loadURL("http://www.google.com");
      }
  }
  ```
- **[Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/)**

  Code Sample:

  ```
  XHTMLPanel panel = new XHTMLPanel();
  panel.setDocument("http://www.google.com");
  ```

  @see [BrowsePanel.java](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/master/flying-saucer-examples/src/main/java/BrowsePanel.java)
- or **[NativeSwing](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/)**

  Code Snippet:

  ```
  final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
  webBrowser.navigate("http://www.google.com");
  ```

  @see [SimpleWebBrowserExample.java](http://djproject.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/djproject/DJNativeSwing-SWTDemo/src/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/demo/examples/webbrowser/SimpleWebBrowserExample.java?pathrev=R-1_0_1)

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason is that HTMLDocument parses three-digit color codes differently from normal. Hence, everything is shown as blue because only the blue byte (and the lowest 4 bits of the green byte) is set.

For example: `#FFF` would be interpreted as `#000FFF`, which is sharp blue.

At least this solved my problem mentioned in the comments. A possible reason for related threads on the background, too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have extended JFrame in your class. So please use editorPane Object for setting the color as below

```
String url="http://google.com";    
editorPane.setEditable(false);
editorPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    try {
        editorPane.setPage(url);
    } ca
```

Answer (score 0):

I once tried using JEditorPane circa JDK1.3 and the support was awfully limited. From what i understand there has not been much advancements in that API to provide support for browsing.

I recommend you checkout DJ [here](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html). Simple to setup and use reliably.