# Why JEditorPane is giving Blue Color?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am trying to create a clone of Web Browser using Swing. I have used JEditorPane but for some reason the background color is always in blue color. This is what I have done

```
JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
editor.setEditable(false);
editor.addHyperlinkListener(this);
editor.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
try{
    editor.setPage("https://www.google.com");
}catch(Exception e){}
```

and
[this is what I am getting as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUQZZ.png)

I don't want to use JavaFx, is there any way how we can fix this using Swing only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browser using JEditorPane forcing blue background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579965/browser-using-jeditorpane-forcing-blue-background)

Comment: *"I am trying to create a clone of Web Browser using Swing."* Swing is not up to that. It only supports a **subset** of ***HTML 3.2***, limited styles and no scripting. Use the Java-FX `WebView` - which embeds an actual browser (AFAIU).

Comment: @AndrewThompson is using outdated software a close reason? I’d find tons of questions we could close then. But letting the background color aside, the Google page seems to be usable with Swing. Starting with JDK 13, the background color seems to be fixed too.

Comment: @Holger *"is using outdated software a close reason?"* I use Swing every other day. It fulfills my (simple) GUI needs. I never mentioned nor meant to  imply it should not be used because of its age. But the context of my comments is *"clone of Web Browser"* - a direct quote from the OP. Swing's HTML support was intended for quick and easy mark-up of rich text. It was never meant to be a pseudo browser, let alone a clone of a browser. Of course it is possible to improve / expand Swing's abilities. E.G. I built support for the applet element into a `JEditorPane` ..

Comment: .. while it was certainly possible (and putting aside that applets are no longer supported at all) if I were to do something, *anything,* similar now, I'd immediately abandon Swing & look to use a `WebView` instead. One good `WebView` example was an app to check Twitter accounts who block you, with the app able to remember accounts to offer in a list. Would not have wasted my time with a `JEditorPane` on that one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was referring to the now-removed comment regarding closing. Using the wrong tool for the job or even trying to achieve an impossible goal aren’t reasons for closing either. These points could be addressed in an answer…

Answer (score 0):

@Kunal, Try changing the color from white to something else

Comment: I have already tried this, but no help

Comment: @Kunal, try to run editor.setBackground(getBackground(color.WHITE));